# How to run heuristic evaluation

Tags: usability, ux-field, usability-study, heuristics

While running a heuristic evaluation, is there a recommended number of tasks? 
I'm struggling with the scoring part. Do I perform all tasks, take notes of the problems and then identify severity based on all problems from all 3 tasks?

Answer (score 2):

In this very good article, from uxmastery, they suggest using 5 tasks: https://uxmastery.com/how-to-run-an-heuristic-evaluation/

But I think what really matters is how you rank the tasks, so you can really focus on the ones that are more critical.